# How to mock/intercept calls to mongoDB atlas during tests? (cloud DB)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest, mongodb-atlas

I have an express app (REST API) which connects to a mongoDB cluster on MongoDB Atlas (the cloud database) during tests. I'm using Mocha to test.

I have an end-to-end test (which uses the database) but for the majority of the tests I want to mock/stub the calls to the database so that it's isolated.

I've tried using nock to intercept the network connections and mock the response, but from what I can see nock is only for `http` calls and mongoDB Atlas uses DNS (starts with `mongodb+srv:`, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-3-6-here-to-SRV-you-with-easier-replica-set-connections) for more info) and I think this is why I can't get this to work.

I've also trying to stub the Model. I'm struggling to get this working but it seems like it might be an option?

```
// The route 
router.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;

  const example = new ExampleModel({ name: name})

  // this should be mocked
  await example.save();

  res.status(200);
});

// The test
describe('POST /example', () => {
  it('Creates an example', async () => {
    // using supertest to make http call to my API app 
    const response = await request(app)
      .post('/test')
      .type("json")
      .send({ 'name': 'test-name' })

    // expect the model to have been created and then saved to the database
  });
});
```

I'm expecting that when I run the test, it will make a POST to the API, which **won't** make a call to the database but will return fake data (as though it had).

Answer (score 0):

I've found some really useful resources and sharing them:

- Isolating mongoose unit tests (including model methods like `findOne` [guide](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/06/10/mongoose-models-and-unit-tests-the-definitive-guide/)
- Stubbing the `save` method on a model: [Stubbing the mongoose save method on a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824519/stubbing-the-mongoose-save-method-on-a-model) (I just used `sinon.stub(ExampleModel.prototype, 'save').

  // example code 
  it('Returns 400 status code', async () => {
        sinon.stub(ExampleModel, 'findOne').returns({ name: 'testName' });
        const saveStub = sinon.stub(ExampleModel.prototype, 'save');

  ```
    const example = new ExampleModel({ name: 'testName' })

    const response = await request(app)
      .post('/api/test')
      .type("json")
      .send({ name: 'testName' })

  sinon.assert.calledWith(Hairdresser.findOne, {
        name: 'testName'
    });

    sinon.assert.notCalled(saveStub)

    assert.equal(response.res.statusCode, 400);
  });
  ```